# How do I turn off the default autocomplete feature in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I created a data validation rule for a set of cells in my Google Sheet so that I could have a simple drop-down and could select items as I type. However, Google Sheets always displays its own autocomplete dialog when I start typing with the "@" symbol, which displays options from my contacts, files, emails, calendar, etc.

[image: sample screenshot]

I literally never want these options, yet I cannot find a way to turn it off. Does anyone out there know how to turn this off?

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. This should be sent as feedback directly to Google. Click Help > Sheets Help > Send feedback on the Google Sheets editor. This will open a sidebar with two options: Report an issue and Submit an idea. P.S. You might find it helpful to learn about *smart chips*: [Insert smart chips in your Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12319513?hl=en)

Comment: i thought this was a community where people help one another sheesh

Comment: @EricBelair What you are looking for is not currently supported by Google Sheets. As end-users, there is no much that we can do other than submit feedback directly to Google.